# Asp.net MVC сайт развернутый в облаке Microsoft Azure Web Sites выдает ошибку

Tags: база-данных, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-websites

Я использую **Visual Studio 2015** Update 3.
Имеется **ASP.NET MVC 4** вебсайт. Фреймворк: .NET Framework 4.5. Сайт работает с базой данной Microsoft (`(LocalDb)\v11.0`). Запуская локально все работает и сайт запускается.

Далее я развернул сайт на **Azure Web Sites** через Visual Studio с помощью опции "**Опубликовать**" (**Publish**). Веб-приложение было успешно опубликовано. Но я не могу открыть его в браузере. Выдает следующую ошибку в браузере:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> *The system cannot find the file specified*
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system
>   cannot find the file specified
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

---

Лог ошибок (stack trace):

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +1000
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +800
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +741
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +85
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +451
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +943
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +22
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +139
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +367
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +129
   WebMatrix.Data.Database.EnsureConnectionOpen() +47
   WebMatrix.Data.<QueryInternal>d__0.MoveNext() +67
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +183
   WebMatrix.Data.Database.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] args) +98
   WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] parameters) +19
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CheckTableExists(IDatabase db, String tableName) +54
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateTablesIfNeeded() +50
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeMembershipProvider(SimpleMembershipProvider simpleMembership, DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean createTables) +71
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeProviders(DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +51
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(String connectionStringName, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +55
   OnlineAuction.MvcApplication.SetSecurityOptions() +60
   OnlineAuction.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +51

[HttpException (0x80004005): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +477
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +176
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +350
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +303

[HttpException (0x80004005): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +657
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +96
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +189
```

---

Строка соединения с БД в файле `Web.config`:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=OnlineAuctionDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\OnlineAuctionDb.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Я загрузил файл `web.config` на [*DropBox*](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0hfstd3hngizln/Web.config?dl=0)

---

Возможно это проблема с базой данных. Я опубликовал весь сайт полностью с помощью опции "**Опубликовать**" в VS. Но возможно база не загрузилась вместе с самим сайтом на облако и сайт не может загрузиться без БД. Но я не уверен. Если проблема в базе данных, то как можно базу добавить к сайту в облаке так, чтобы они взаимодействовали и сайт работал как и на локалке?

---

Comment: Я создал новый ASP.NET проект, добавил в него базу данных и задеплоил на Azure Website. Ошибок не вылезло, но Connection String другой: <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20161121123622.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20161121123622;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Да. Дефолтный ASP проект работает сразу. Проблемы начинаются если используется в проекте Entity Framework Code First. При этом начинаются танцы с бубном при настройке Code-first migrations. Ошибка теперь не в отсутствии базы а в том что в базе нет ни одной таблицы.

Comment: LocalDb не следует использовать с веб-сайтами.

Comment: Проблема в Code First migrations. Строка соединения в вебконфиге игнорируется.

Comment: Тут у кого-то такая же проблема: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870996/using-a-localdb-mdf-file-on-azure. Там по правильному ответу дали ссылку на то как при помощи танцев с бубном запустить всё это на Azure Websites.

Comment: А то что LoaclDb лучше не использовать, это да... Может даже лучше взять SQL Azure Free? Хотя там совсем дохлая база...Но может быть и хватит. От проекта зависит.

Comment: Я базу создавал непосредствнно на Azure. И уже указывал строку соединения к ней при деплое (точнее она автоматически вывелась при деплое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalDB предназначен только для разработки, и в Azure App Services не поддерживается. AttachDbFilename - тоже хак для разработки, а не для полноценного хостинга.

Вам нужна будет полноценная база Azure SQL (судя по всему она у вас есть).

Connection String в Azure App Services можно переписать на уровне самого аппсервиса через портал, в Application Settings / Connection String.

Если connection string из web.config не подхватывается - значит он переписан в портале.

Убедитесь что connection string там актуальный, называется правильно, и что он указывает на полноценную базу, а не на LocalDB или на AttachDBFilename.