# ASP MVC 5 Проблемы развертывания в Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-websites

Использую VS 2017. Сама визуальная часть отлично публикуется и доступна по url. Но сама база данных почему-то не публикуется.
При создании проекта использовал локальную базу данных и подход database first.
В чем дело? Что я делаю не так, может базу надо как то отдельно добавлять в ажур?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LocalDB скорее всего предназначены только для тестирования приложения при разработке . 
при публикации приложения в эжур - нужно создавать базу данных у них

[пример](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-get-started)

вот что они пишут 
Развертывание приложения в Azure
Чтобы запустить приложение в облаке, выполните следующие действия:

Создайте облачную службу Azure.
Создайте базу данных SQL Azure.
Создайте учетную запись хранения Azure.
Настройте приложение для использования базы данных SQL Azure, когда оно работает в облаке Azure.
Настройте приложение на использование вашей учетной записи хранения при запуске в Azure.
Разверните проект в облачной службе Azure.

но там ещё написано что при тестировании приложения через эжур может использоваться локальная база , как изменить вэб конфиг там тоже написано

[здесь уже обсуждалось подобное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593178/asp-net-mvc-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5-microsoft-azure-web-sites-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83)

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database

Развертывание приложения в Azure

В Visual Studio щелкните правой кнопкой мыши проект в обозревателе решений и выберите Опубликовать в контекстном меню.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откроется мастер Публикация веб-сайта .

Откройте вкладку Параметры в левой части диалогового окна Публикация веб-сайта.

В разделе ApplicationDbContext выберите базу данных, созданную при создании проекта.

В разделе ContactManagerContext выберите Execute Code First Migrations (Выполнить миграции Code First).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Щелкните Опубликовать.

Войдите в систему как user1@contoso.com (с паролем P_assw0rd1) и убедитесь, что можете изменять данные.

Выйдите из системы.

Перейдите в консоль разработчиков Google и на вкладке Учетные данные обновите URI перенаправления и JavaScript Orgins для использования URL-адреса Azure.
Войдите с помощью Google или Facebook. При этом учетная запись Google или Facebook добавится к роли canEdit . Если появится ошибка HTTP 400 с сообщением The redirect URI in the request: https://contactmanager{my version}.azurewebsites.net/signin-google did not match a registered redirect URI (URI перенаправления в запросе https://contactmanager {моя версия}.azurewebsites.net/signin-google не совпадает с зарегистрированным URI перенаправления), вам придется подождать, пока распространятся изменения.

Если эта ошибка будет появляться несколько минут, проверьте правильность универсальных кодов ресурсов.